# Product custom attribute display in backend

Tags: magento2, orders, price, backend, items

I have created one order from backend in **Magento 2.0.7** and selected item for order at that time.

I want to display product custom attribute `Best Price` with item details.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to Override this file

```
\vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\templates\order\details.phtml
```

and then add your column and values here.

Comment: Thanx let me check.

Answer (score 0):

Set the values of “Visible on Product View Page on Front-end” and “Used in Product Listing” options under storefront Properties to "Yes" while creating the attribute to display it in Product list and view pages.